# want to start spinner add category but show spinner first category text

Tags: android, listview, android-volley, android-spinner

my app contain listview with spinner and when select spinner category after that value is dividing by category but when spinner noting select then show all value in listview 
but there is problem my spinner containing value from first item of spinner

```
 private void getData() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j_obj = null;
                    try {
                        j_obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        result = j_obj.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getStudents(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void getStudents(JSONArray j) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
            students.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String text_spinner = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    j_data.setSpintext(text_spinner);
    makeJsonArrayRequest();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Get Value from spinner"    +text_spinner, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

[image]

help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple trick you can make is add the category name at the 0th(zero th) index of "student" collection , then in Spinner's onItemSelected listner ignore the functionality of the position is 0(zero).